# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when doing a POST using AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: objective-c, http, post, afnetworking-2

My code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager] ;
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializerWithWritingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[manager POST:[_urlBase stringByAppendingPathComponent:_urlRequest]
         parameters:paramDictionary
         success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject){
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                 [self AFRequestFinished:responseObject];
             });
         }
         failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error){
             NSLog(@"JSON ERROR PARAMETERS: %@", error);
         }
];
```

I am using this `POST` request to send several types of data up to a server along with pictures.
 I am using something very similar for the `GET` request and it works fine. Whenever I run this code I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS CODE=1` error on the following line of `AFNetworking 2.0.` The responseObject is `0x0`:

```
responseObject = [self.responseSerializer responseObjectForResponse:task.response data:[NSData dataWithData:self.mutableData] error:&serializationError];
```

The above line of code is within the if/else method in:

```
- (void)URLSession:(__unused NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

***UPDATE***

I ran instruments on the code, and it there is a zombie present. `AFNetworking` is trying to make a call to the `NSError`, but it has been deallocated. I believe this has arisen because the `POST` call initially succeeds, but there is still an error that is flagged. So it initially thinks there is no error and sets it to `nil`, but then tries to call for it in the error block of the `POST`.

Comment: Is `self.mutableData` `nil`? If so, then this might be a good issue to post on the [AFNetworking issues page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues).

Comment: `self.mutableData != nil` the issue seems to be a call on the error that has been deallocated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the most recent version, you may be experiencing [**this known issue**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1885) when the JSON serializer returns an error.  You can work around this until a new release is made by:

- removing the `@autoreleasepool` in the serializer, or
- changing the scope of the error to outside the autorelease pool

(Both solutions are outlined in the issue linked above.)

On a side note, there's no need to dispatch to the main queue in the completion handler.  AFNetworking guarantees that completion blocks are called on the main thread.

Comment: Thank you! This finally got it working. I will update my completion handler to remove dispatch_async as well.